# Styling devise.en.yaml in views - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, frontend, semantic-ui

In my rails app, notices and alerts are rendered to the front-end with `<%= notice %>` and are stored in `message-board/config/locales/devise.en.yaml` when looking at the web inspector they don’t show any elements attached to them. I am trying to style with Semantic UI.

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/BrandonKlotz/message-board/)

Answer (score 0):

OK, you can try the following for design message

On your code

```
<%= notice %>
```

Replace with below

```
<% if notice.present? %>
  <div class="ui message">
      <i class="close icon"></i>
      <div class="header">
          Notice!
      </div>
      <p><%= notice %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Now design will be like below if your `Semantic UI` work properly in your app

[image]

The close icon does not work automatically, for this behavior must be defined using Javascript, for example:

```
$('.message .close')
  .on('click', function() {
    $(this)
      .closest('.message')
      .transition('fade');
});
```

`Semantic UI` example from [here](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/message.html#dismissable-block)

Hope to help